# Check that folder contains files with specific extension (windows bat file)

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am trying to create a windows bat file that checks if a folder contains files of a specify extension and the runs some basic command. Something like:

```
set inputFolder=%1

if [%inputFolder%.containsExtension("class")] goto exists

goto end
:exists

:end
```

but how do I check the extension of the files in inputFolder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is <strike>using a `dir` command and checking the ERRORLEVEL environment variable</strike> using EXISTS directive.

```
set inputFolder=%1
set extension=%2

IF EXIST %inputFolder%\*.%extension% GOTO exists

goto end

:exists

echo exists

:end
```

Comment: Why I thought of using dir before testing if EXIST worked with "*" is beyond me...